# How to Set backGround Image to Navigation Page Bar in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking to set BackgroundImage to the NavBar in NavigationPage Xamarin.Forms app but I can't find an answer. Dose anybody know how to do it? I can change the Color property but I need the company logo in the top bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is not supported by the Xamarin.Forms framework, you'll need to create a custom renderer for NavigationBar (the class to render is as far as I understand is *NavigationRenderer* or *NavigationPageRenderer*).

Then in the render class in android add a drawable image and in iOS a UIImage to the top bar.

**Edit** - 
 I thought of another solution - without using custom renders, you can achieve this by removing the existing bar, by setting in each page this command:

`NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false)`

And creating a custom navigation bar which is wrapped in a grid, it should look something like this:

```
<Grid>
   <Image Source="BackgroundImage.png"/> <!-- This should fill the grid -->
   <Image Source="back_button" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFit" >
      <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding NavigateBackCommand}"/>
      </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Ido, do you know on any sample code that does it?

Comment: You can try this link :
http://www.morganskinner.com/2015/01/xamarin-formsusing-background-images-on.html

Comment: Thanks again, Ill try to implement you's code and will update

Comment: can see the button but not the background image

Comment: Hi Shimon, I have added a sample solution with this template which is working as expected, you can download and look here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=27833238531090914137

Comment: @IdoT, what if you were trying to do that in the c# view? (instead of XAML)?

Comment: @IdoT : download link is broken.